# Smart paging rendering pager different from the Devel model

Tags: paging, theming

I am on Drupal 7 and I have the Smart Paging module enabled. When theming my module, I want the page numbers to appear as regular links. This seems to be the natural behavior. Here is the HTML available on the Devel module on the render section for [smart_paging]:

```
<div class="smart-paging-pager">
    <h2 class="element-invisible">Páginas</h2>
    <div class="item-list">
        <ul class="pager">
            <li class="pager-current first">1</li>
            <li class="pager-item"><a href="/node/178/devel/render/pagina/0/1" title="Ir para a página 2" class="active">2</a></li>
            <li class="pager-item"><a href="/node/178/devel/render/pagina/0/2" title="Ir para a página 3" class="active">3</a></li>
            <li class="pager-next"><a href="/node/178/devel/render/pagina/0/1" title="Ir para a próxima página" class="active">próx ›</a></li>
            <li class="pager-last last"><a href="/node/178/devel/render/pagina/0/2" title="Ir para a última página" class="active">fim »</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the links to the pages 1, 2, 3... are being replaced with a select list box with the options Page 1, Page 2, Page 3. I don't know how to change that behavior and make the links render as... links, exactly the way the HTML is showing.

I am using the Omega theme and I know it is not the theme replacing my pager because if I switch to another theme, the same change is applied to the pager... Do you know where I can configure the pager display? Do I have to go to template.php? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: go to the Smart Paging settings page and uncheck "Use javascript pager as progressive enhancement for Drupal native pager"... as simple as that...